# I can not clone a Github Repo due to identification denied

Tags: git, github, ssh

I apologize I have been going at this for days already. I am trying to clone a github repo for a project I am doing.  When I tried to clone it, it came back that

```
Cloning into 'send-email-lambda'...
no such identity: /custom/dir/custom-key: No such file or directory
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

I found out that I did not have a ssh key registered in my github and I went through that process. It was kind of a pain. I generated a new ssh key and added it to my github.  I followed the github docs and it still does not work. I tried to check the log but I do not know what I am looking for.

```
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
Brian'sMac:code briansantos$ ssh -vT git@github.com
OpenSSH_7.9p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/briansantos/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 48: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to github.com port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /custom/dir/custom-key type -1
debug1: identity file /custom/dir/custom-key-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.9
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version babeld-8112423e
debug1: no match: babeld-8112423e
debug1: Authenticating to github.com:22 as 'git'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: rsa-sha2-512
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:nThbg6kXUpJWGl7E1IGOCspRomTxdCARLviKw6E5SY8
debug1: Host 'github.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/briansantos/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: /custom/dir/custom-key  explicit
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-dss>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /custom/dir/custom-key
no such identity: /custom/dir/custom-key: No such file or directory
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
Brian'sMac:code briansantos$
```

Can someone please give me some insight?

Comment: What's in your `~/.ssh/config` file? It looks like you're telling ssh to take the GitHub identity from a file named `/custom/dir/custom-key`; do you have a file with that name?

Comment: How do I redirect it to go to the -/.ssh/config?

Comment: That question doesn't make sense. ssh reads this config file; you don't *tell* it to, it just *does*. Whatever you put in the config file, that's your configuration. What I said above is that it looks like you created this configuration file and put stuff in it, and the stuff you put in it might well be wrong, so it would be helpful if you would edit your question to show the contents of your configuration file.

Comment: I'm not sure how to check the contents of that config file.

Answer (score 0):

As a quick fix, I'll suggest you to clone with `https`, that will allow you to sign in with your `github` credentials.